# Denotation of probability symbols

Tags: probability, notation

May I kindly clarify if the following mean the same thing?

$$P(AB) = P(A \cap B)$$

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A \cup B)$ is the same as $P(A \lor B)$ is the same as $P(A \operatorname{or} B)$.

$P(A \cap B)$ is the same as $P(A \land B)$ is the same as $P(A \operatorname{and} B)$ is the same as $P(AB)$.