# Complement of Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am wondering I may get some advice if P(A|Ū) is equals to 1- P(A|U)?

Many thanks once again.

Comment: short answer is no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Take some events, $A$, $U$ and $\bar U$ where $P(A)$ is typically high. e.g. A = "drank milk as an infant" and where U is some subset of everyone, like U = "was born with green eyes". I imagine P(A|U) is somewhere above 0.99. What would you think $P(A|\bar U)$ should be? Less than 0.01? Or much, much higher?

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Glen_b! Great analogy! Really appreciate it. If I have P(A|U), how will you advice that I can find P(A|Ū)? Thank you so much once again!

Comment: You know the left,blue part as a fraction of the left part, you want the right,blue part as a fraction of the right part. To get that, you need more information - see the diagram.  For example, you could work it out if you knew P(A) and P(U). If you want an extensive answer, either add it to your question or ask a new one.

Comment: A useful answer to a related question to your new question is [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55663/denotation-of-probability-symbols/55665#55665)

Comment: Thanks Glen. I've opened a new question via http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83459/finding-pa-from-known-pau-pa-and-pu