# Finding P(A|Ū) from known P(A|U), P(A) and P(U)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am wondering I may get some advice.

If I wanted to find the value of P(A|Ū), and have values for P(A|U), P(A) and P(U), is there any probability functions that I can use?

Many thanks once again.

Comment: Since this now starts to look like standard book-work, you should probably add the `self-study` tag; see its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: Hint: What does the _law of total probability_ say? Of the five quantities on the two sides of the equality, how many do you know (or can compute from the given information)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should know these already -

fact 1: $P(A) =  P(A\bar U) + P(AU)$

fact 2: $P(\bar U) = 1-P(U)$

fact 3: $P(AU) = P(A|U)P(U)$

(see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Summary_of_probabilities) for example)

Can you do it now?

[image]